# Replace Tridion 2011 default datepicker

Tags: 2011

We have defined some fields in a schema of the type "Date".

When we make new components of this schema, you have to use the default datepicker within the Content Manager. This datepicker is far from optimal (drop-down months instead of arrows, time in 3 fields); and perhaps the biggest issue: you can't type a date-time, you MUST use the datepicker.

My question is: Is there an official update/hotfix for the datepicker (as it is core-functionality). Or are there plug-ins available? If none are available how can we implement a more modern jquery-like datepicker?

Comment: I am not sure about update\hotfix but you can always write a GUI extension for your custom datepicker.

Comment: Consider joining [Tridion Ideas](http://ideas.sdltridion.com/) which lets you submit ideas to SDL product management. I submitted [an idea for the same functionality](http://ideas.sdltridion.com/ideas/detail.asp?i=2300) that you may want to "upvote." In terms of extending Schema fields, the [Field Behavior Injection extension](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-field-behavior-injection/) has some examples.

Comment: I will look into the GUI extension, perhaps that will give the client the functionality they desire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no update/hotfix for the datepicker and there is no supported way of replacing it with custom control. So you can do that, but this wouldn't be easy :)

Comment: Not the answer that I was hoping for, but thanks for the info!